# How to access replayed build's current status in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When i replay a build, I would like to access that build's current status. I checked `currentBuild` object's properties in [here](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Jenkins_currentBuild) but could not find any solution.

```
def replayClassName = 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause'
def cause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses(replayClassName)
def isReplay = !(cause.isEmpty())

if(isReplay) {
    if(REPLAYED_BUILD_STATUS == 'SUCCESS'){
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

I have tryed `currentBuild.result` and `currentResult` properties but they return `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO replays not usefull in scripted pipeline
But if you want to get couse build result you must at first get that build:

> and it may be needs approval in jenkins

**pipeline :**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def replay_couse = currentBuild
                       .rawBuild
                       .getCause(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause)                       
                    if(replay_couse){
                       print replay_couse.getOriginalNumber()
                       print replay_couse.getOriginal().result
                    }
                    else{
                        print 'not replayed'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

some refs : [getOriginal()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/replay/ReplayCause.html#getOriginal()) [Jenkins-examples](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#get-build-cause) [getCouse](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun/getCause)

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried your suggestion but it gives me an error. `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getCause() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.replay.ReplayCause]
Possible solutions: getCause(java.lang.Class), getCauses(), getClass(), getCharset(), getACL(), getTarget()`

Comment: I update solution,
You pass string while getCause() uses classes

Comment: Your final solution works well! Thank you Sam!